# javascript output buffer

Tags: javascript, buffer

Is there any method to get the entire output into a buffer in javascript.In php we can do with ob_start().I want an equivalent function in javascript to store the entire source code into a buffer.I want to minify the html page(source code) with javascript on loading.How can I do that.Please help me

Comment: I think you need to tell us what the actual outcome should be. Perhaps it is not buffering you are looking for. There is no point in doing anything with the source on the client - if you want to minify stuff, you need to do it in the PHP

Answer (score 1):

Minifying the markup with JavaScript is pointless as the markup has already been downloaded by the user.

To get the entire document's HTML, use `document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML`.